# Post ID removed from end of URL then how to Redirect to original URL with post ID?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I'm currently using WordPress in the permalink structure as 
https://www.example.com/%postname%/%post_id%/

So the when I publish a post the URL will be displayed at https://www.example.com/sample-post/4568/

I can view the content in both of these URLs - https://www.example.com/sample-post/4568/ and https://www.example.com/sample-post/

But I want to redirect the URL without post-ID to the original URL with Post-ID.

How to achieve it and displaying content on both URL will it cause the duplicate content issue?